Mold on side of paint can
I started to paint the trim in our bedroom and half way through I noticed mold on the inside of the top of the can. None was in the actually paint. And I was only putting my paint brush in the can. I don’t pour it out or touch the mold. How concerned should I be? I’m nervous.

That should be no issue.

Cringe! Run screaming from moldy paint. We've had a number of horror stories come through here where people painted with moldy paint, and the smell was irrepressible and resisted all attempts to get rid of it, and after several attempts to topcoat it with primer and new finish coats, they wound up having to strip all the paint or re-drywall.  Don't use it. Paint is cheap.

@Harper, Op didn't state there was a smell, and didn't even notice the mold until after starting to paint.  This is a very minor thing.  If stated there was mold all over the can, then yes I agree.
